# Getting error when trying to write df to database from pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I getting json from HDFS, transform it and try to write df in database. 
Error:

```
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I saw other post with similiar problem but don't know what to do in my case

> Spark version: 2.3.1 PySpark: 2.3.1

Code:

```
df.write \
.jdbc("jdbc:clickhouse://adqm2.gu.local:8123", "esia_dev.bill_agg_test",
      properties={"user": "user", "password": "password"})
```

Code2

```
df.write \
.format("jdbc") \
.mode("append") \
.option("driver", "ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver") \
.option("url", "jdbc:clickhouse://adqm2.gu.local:8123/esia_dev")\
.option("driver", "ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver")\
.option("dbtable", "esia_dev.bill_agg_test")\
.option("user", "user") \
.option("password", "password")\
.save()
```

*P.S When i save to csv it is work*

Answer (score 0):

Writing to disk typically looks like;

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet('/folder1/folder2')
```

Writing to a table typically looks like;

```
df.write \
    .mode("append") \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw") \
    .option("url", f"jdbc:sqlserver://server.sql.azuresynapse.net:1433;database=dbname;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.sql.azuresynapse.net;loginTimeout=30") \
    .option("useAzureMSI", "true") \
    .option("enableServicePrincipalAuth", "true") \
    .option("dbTable", f"{schema}.{table}") \
    .option("truncate", "true") \
    .option("tempDir", f"abfss://lakeloc.dfs.core.windows.net/temp") \
    .option("maxErrors", 100) \
    .save()
```

There are variants of course depending on connector / situation, but try to make it look more like the above, or provide more details.

Comment: yeah, i trying that template, but get the same trouble (i added this variant to question)

Comment: Is your Spark version supported for the writing operation / jbdc connector?

Comment: yeah, i checked it in docs
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases